# @font-face link to local URL does not function

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

```
@font-face{
   font-family:'Above';
   src: url(C:\Windows\Fonts\AboveDEMORegular);
   font-family:'banshrift';
   src: url(../fonts/bahnschrift.ttf);
   font-family: 'century gothic';
   src: url(../fonts/GOTHIC.TTF);
}

.backgroundg{
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom ,rgb(217,165,122),rgb(214,150,187),rgb(195,142,173)100%);
   height: 700px;
   margin: -10px -8px;
}
#logo{
   padding: 40px 0 0 52px;
   display: inline;
   width: 270px;
}
#navlist{
   display: inline;
   list-style: none;
   float: right;
   margin: 50px 70px 0 0 ;
}
#navlist li{
   display: inline;
   margin: 0 20px 0 100px;
   font-family:'banshrift';
   font-size: 30px;
}
```

I linked the banschrift ttf file to my CSS (I did copy it from the system and put it in a folder I made named fonts) and the font doesn't work on the list I made.
I also tried it with the Above DEMO ttf but nothing.
if anyone could give me some tips about what should be done, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @font-face separate for each font-family

```
 @font-face{
           font-family:'banshrift';
           src: url(../fonts/bahnschrift.ttf);
        }
        @font-face{
           font-family: 'century gothic';
           src: url(../fonts/GOTHIC.TTF);
        }
```

Try the @font-face like this